# Firebase Vue Vuefire UID not availabe in time

Tags: firebase, vue.js, firebase-authentication, vuefire

I'm trying to get vuefire/vue/firebase to work when there is auth and separate users. I can get it to work when I pass a UID manually...

```
let booksRef = db.ref('Users/' + 'SOhUKhcWzVRZmqe3AfcWMRwQR4r2' + '/Books');
```

But, when I try and replace the hard coded uid with one that comes from Firebase, I get a null result... It is basically not ready at the time of the call, even if the user is logged in...:

```
beforeCreate: function() {
  var context = this;
  Firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
  if (user) {
    currentUser = user;
    context.currentUserId = user.uid;
    context.currentUserEmail = user.email;
    context.signedIn = true;
    } 
    else {
    context.currentUserId = null;
    context.currentUserEmail = null;        }
});
```

How can I ensure I get the UID first before I create the path to the dataset?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I figured this out, with the help of a GitHub example.

I'm providing the GitHub link below. But, in short, you have to do things a bit differently when using auth and UID... It's not well documented by Vuefire. You need to use a VueJS lifecycle method **beforeCreate**, along with a special Vuefire binding **$bindAsArray**.

Here's a snippet that shows the usage:

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  beforeCreate: function() {

    // Setup Firebase onAuthStateChanged handler
    //
    // https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.Auth
    // https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.Auth#onAuthStateChanged
    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
      if (user) {
        this.user = user
        // https://github.com/vuejs/vuefire/blob/master/src/vuefire.js#L169
        this.$bindAsArray('messages', db.ref('messages/' + user.uid))
      } else {
        // https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.Auth#signInAnonymously
        firebase.auth().signInAnonymously().catch(console.error)
      }
    }.bind(this))

  },

  // Initialize reactive props, bind later when user is available
  data: {
    user: {},
    messages: []
  },
```

[See the full github example here:](https://github.com/chrisbraddock/vuefire-auth-demo/blob/master/index.html)